# Bash - Convert comma separated list

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that works on a list of files.  If I want to work on all files in the same directory then

```
FILES=*.ext

for i in $FILES; do
  something on "$i"
done
```

works OK, the problem comes when I want to work on just a selection of files and not everything.  How do I convert a comma separated list of files, which may or may not contain spaces into the same format, so that I can store it in $FILES and use the same code?

Many thanks, in advance

David Shaw

Comment: Would you mind to provide some sample data?

Answer (score 3):

The correct thing to do is not use a delimited list of filenames but use an array (and avoid uppercase variable names), this will avoid the problem of filenames containing your separator (e.g. `,`) and is the idiomatic approach:

```
files=( *foo*.ext1 *bar*.ext2 file1 "file 2 with a space" )

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    do_something_with "${file}"
done
```

Unless you have no control over how `$files` is populated this is what you want, if your script gets fed a comma-separated list and you absolutely cannot avoid it then you can set `IFS` accordingly as in @BroSlow's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22742288/612462).

Since globbing does the right thing when expanding filenames with spaces are not a problem (not even in your example).

You might also want to check [`extended globbing (extglob)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) to be able to match more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting your question correctly you can just the internal field separator (IFS) in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to comma and then have word-splitting take care of the rest, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="file1,file2 with space,file3,file4 with space"

IFS=','
for i in $FILES; do
  echo "File = [$i]"
done
```

Which would output

```
File = [file1]
File = [file2 with space]
File = [file3]
File = [file4 with space]
```

Note, as [Adrian Frühwirth pointed out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742221/bash-convert-comma-separated-list/22742288#comment34663310_22742288), this will fail if the filenames can contain commas.

Comment: Yes, but this is not how you do it. You just shift the problem and now it will break on filenames with commas.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I'm still interpreting the problem as he has a list of files separated by commas and wants to iterate over it. If the filenames themselves can contain commas then the problem is pretty much unsolvable.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem and OP just needs to know that they should not store - nor is it necessary - a list of comma-separated files/patterns. If you use an array and do it properly you avoid all of those problems.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Completely agree with using an array, process substitution/piping directly, even `\n` separated list, etc... instead of comma separated if possible.

Comment: If you note in your answer that this is generally a bad idea unless you have no control over the input (i.e. you get fed a comma-separated list and cannot avoid it) and restore `IFS` to its old value as is good practice after the loop I will upvote since you are right, this is what OP asked for even though it's ugly :/

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for - but the issue of filenames with commas never occured to me (duh!).  The idea was to operate on all files unless an optional parameter of the form -f file1,file2,file3... is passed to the script and it was this that I wanted split.

Comment: @DavidShaw You should make it space separated, in which case is someone does `./script -f file1 "some, weird file" file3`, you can handle the arguments properly, because [tag:bash] will do the quote/escape processing beforehand.